# in jest test enzyme.shallow throws Unexpected token < error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, enzyme, jestjs

I am currently setting up unit tests with usage of following stack:

- react (v15) components are written with typescript (.tsx)
- test setup is done with jest(v21) and enzyme(v3)
- test files are written as plain js-files

Unfortunately something seems to go wrong with enzyme as I keep getting an error:

```
 wrapper = enzyme.shallow(<Stepper>bla</Stepper>)
                             ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

  at new Script (vm.js:51:7)
      at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
      at new Promise (<anonymous>)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
```

The respective test file looks like this:

```
var React = require('react');
var enzyme = require('enzyme');
var Stepper = require('./Stepper').default;

var wrapper;

describe('Stepper', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    wrapper = enzyme.shallow(<Stepper>bla</Stepper>)
  });

  test('has bla', () => {
    expect(wrapper.contains('bla')).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

I configured jest as followed in my package.json:

```
"jest": {
  "transform": {
    "^.+\\.(tsx|ts)$": "typescript-babel-jest"
  },
  "moduleFileExtensions": [
    "ts",
    "tsx",
    "js"
  ],
  "testMatch": [
    "<rootDir>/src/**/**/*.test.js"
  ],
  "moduleNameMapper": {
    "\\.(css|scss)$": "identity-obj-proxy"
  },
  "setupTestFrameworkScriptFile": "<rootDir>/setupTests.js"
}
```

And my setupTests.js file looks like this:

```
var enzyme = require('enzyme');
var Adapter = require('enzyme-adapter-react-15');

enzyme.configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });
```

I am running out of ideas what could be causing the issue, does anyone know a solution to this?

Comment: The error is not specifically caused by enzyme. It's because the jsx `<Stepper>bla</Stepper>` is not correctly interpreted as if React was not correctly imported into this scope. Is there a certain reason you are using requirejs instead of es6 modules?

Comment: How should react be imported correctly then? If I am not using es5 syntax I am getting tones of syntax errors such as for 'import'

Comment: Btw if I am putting e.g. <div></div> instead of <Stepper></Stepper> I am still getting the same error. Also I am getting the same error no matter if I use enzyme's 'enzyme.shallow' or jest's 'renderer.create'

Comment: yeah because `<div></div>` is also jsx and you can only write jsx if React was correctly imported. I guess the reason is, that babel needs to run on your test file which has a `.js` ending, but you are only transforming `.tsx` and `.ts`. Try to add `.js` to your jest transforms in your `package.json`. I can only strongly recommend you to make yourself familiar with webpack + babel and es6 as it makes your life much easier writing code.

Comment: @trinx but how is it correctly imported? How is var React = require('react); not sufficient? Or do I need to import it at another place, too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need your test file to be transpiled by babel because it contains `jsx`. Using jsx requires to have React imported and the file to be transpiled by babel.

At the moment you do only transpile files ending with `.tsx` or `.ts` as definded in your `package.json`. Add `.js` as your test file ends on `.js`:

```
  "transform": {
    "^.+\\.(tsx|ts|js)$": "typescript-babel-jest"
  },
```

Alternatively write your test file in typescript and use `.tsx` as the file ending.

Comment: @SeBe your welcome. Btw: you should also be able to use es6 syntax inside your tests if you transpile them.

Answer (score 0):

First install ts-jest then use this command

```
npx ts-jest config:init
```

This work for me.