# Jest SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, enzyme

I'm want to test a component in a React app using [Jest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jest_(JavaScript_framework)) [Enzyme](https://github.com/enzymejs/enzyme) with TypeScript. I follow the instructions on [the Jest site](https://jestjs.io/), but for some reason I get:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

I can test test some functions. There isn't any problem with that, but when I use a component, I get an error.

This is the Jest configuration in file *[package.json](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/configuring-npm/package-json/)*:

```
"jest": {
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.tsx?$": "ts-jest"
    },
    "testMatch": ["**/__tests__/*.(ts|tsx)"],
    "snapshotSerializers": ["enzyme-to-json/serializer"],
    "setupFilesAfterEnv": ["<rootDir>/src/setupEnzyme.ts"],
    "unmockedModulePathPatterns": ["node_modules/react/", "node_modules/enzyme/"]
  }
```

#### Enzyme configuration

```
import { configure } from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';

configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });
```

```
export default class TesComponent extends Component {
    render(){
        return (
            <div>test</div>
        )
    }
}
```

```
import { shallow } from 'enzyme'
import TestCompoenent from '../TestComponent'

test('component testing', () => {
    const component = shallow(<TestCompoenent />)
    expect(component.contains(<div>test</div>)).toBeTruthy()
})
```

This is the error:

```
Jest encountered an unexpected token

    This usually means that you are trying to import a file which Jest cannot parse, e.g., it's not plain JavaScript.

    By default, if Jest sees a Babel config, it will use that to transform your files, ignoring "node_modules".

    Here's what you can do:
     • To have some of your "node_modules" files transformed, you can specify a custom "transformIgnorePatterns" in your config.
     • If you need a custom transformation specify a "transform" option in your config.
     • If you simply want to mock your non-JS modules (e.g. binary assets) you can stub them out with the "moduleNameMapper" config option.

    You'll find more details and examples of these config options in the docs:
    https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration.html

    Details:

    /home/user/Documents/local-platform/frontend/src/pages/__tests__/settigs.test.tsx:9
        var component = enzyme_1.shallow(<TestComponent_1.default />);
                                         ^

    SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

      at ScriptTransformer._transformAndBuildScript (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:471:17)
      at ScriptTransformer.transform (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:513:25)
```

I expect for the tests to pass, because Test Component does include `<div>test</div>`.

Comment: Post your `TestCompoenent ` also.

Comment: i've edited post

Comment: Try `jest --clearCache`

Comment: got the same error:(

Comment: Any solutions for NextJs?

Comment: One line says "`TesComponent`", without "t" (`export default class TesComponent`), another says "`TestCompoenent`", an extra "e" (`import TestCompoenent from '../TestComponent'`), and yet another "`TestComponent`". Which one is it????

Answer (score 32):

Try changing `tsconfig.json`

`"jsx": "preserve"` `->` `"jsx": "react"`

Comment: This option specifies how the output should be generated(i.e. JSX syntax converted to, type checking). Details https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsx.html#basic-usage

Comment: Finally!! Just in case, changing it to "react" fixed my main issue. However, it throws some other errors. Solved by replacing it with `react-jsx`, as mentioned by Dan Barclay (https://stackoverflow.com/a/65539274/1883199)

Comment: This is not working in nextjs. ``- jsx was set to preserve (next.js implements its own optimized jsx transform)``

Answer (score 5):

Adding the `@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx` as plugin to babel in `babel.config.js` resolved this issue for me.

```
module.exports = {
  presets: [['@babel/preset-env', { targets: { node: 'current' } }], '@babel/preset-typescript'],
  plugins: ['@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx'],
};
```

I hope that will be helpful to anyone. Spent a few hours trying different approaches before finding that

Comment: would have been useful if you had shared where you found that :-)

Answer (score 2):

It seems that your configuration does not process the TypeScript file (.tsx) properly.

Here is part of my working configuration:

```
"jest": {
    "transform": {
       "^.+\\.tsx?$": "ts-jest",
    },
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
       "ts",
       "tsx",
       "js",
       "json"
    ],
    "setupTestFrameworkScriptFile": "<rootDir>/src/setupSpecs.ts"
}
```

I have used `setupTestFrameworkScriptFile` instead of `setupFilesAfterEnv`.

Comment: i get message saying `Option "setupTestFrameworkScriptFile" was replaced by configuration "setupFilesAfterEnv", which supports multiple paths`, when i press enter to continue i get the same error

Comment: how about adding "moduleFileExtension" ?

Comment: please provide test repo, with miniam l package json, jest config, and those 2 simple   tsx files

Comment: Please see my answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/70270290/7387345